# “Can I not read it”?

Tags: questions, negation, modal-verbs

If a person is asking about permission *not* to read something, he doesn't want to read it and asks not to read it. Can we use the phrase “Can I not read it”? Is it correct?

Comment: The meaning might be clear when *spoken* with intonation, but it is ambiguous when written.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used it in speaking. But, can you provide better alternative? Thank you!

Comment: "Do you mind if I don't read it?"

Comment: Thank you! It helped me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I can not attend to something" meaning "I'm free not to attend to something"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203766/i-can-not-attend-to-something-meaning-im-free-not-to-attend-to-something)

Comment: Kind of, but it doesn't my question fully.)

Comment: The point is that "Can I not read it?" (unless spoken with a particular intonation) is a formal way of asking "Can't I read it" (Am I not allowed to?)

Answer (score 0):

"Do I have to read it?"
That's natural and unambiguous.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this sentence is that it is syntactically ambiguous as to whether *not* negates *can* or *read*. Sentences of this structure are usually used with the intention that *not* negate *can*, and are consequently more likely to be interpreted that way, unless the context or the intonation indicates that the other reading is intended. In one wants to completely avoid the problem, one should use some entirely different formulation, that avoids combining *not* and *can*, such as 'Is it OK if I don't read it?' or 'Can I trust you to read it for me and give me your opinion?.